# how should I automation of work with Python

Tags: python, automation

I'm very beginner to python but I know intermediate JavaScript. I have one project to complete this is like a scraper but I want to automate some work for me.
1 ) I have a Excel with more than 1000 data and it also has URLs. I want to code that python visit every URL from that Excel sheet and search first page for Some predefine search texts (List of Texts)
2 ) If my code find any of the Text from that web page then it should return true else false
I want any idea or logic to do this kind of process. Any help will make my head pain less 
it is very heavy work which is not very good idea to do in JavaScript that's why I want to do it in Python

Comment: You can use Selenium for the purpose (Supports both chrome and Firefox) and please clarify what do you want to do. You just can't search for ideas here.

Comment: "I know intermediate JavaScript" so whats the problem to do it using js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this would be to get the requests module. Then learn how to use the csv module which can read spreadsheets such as excel spreadsheets. Then here is what you want to do

```
import csv
import requests

URLS = []

def GetUrlFromCSVFile():
    global URLS 
    #Figure out how to get link from csv file then append them to the URLS list

for url in URLS:
    r = requests.get(URL, headers=#You Should Probs get some headers)
    if whatever_keyword_u_looking_for in r.text:
        print("Found")
    else:
        print("Not here")
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

1. Read about the csv library - to read the content of an excel file.
2. Read about the requests library - to get the page's content from its URL.
3. Read about regular expressions in the re library.